# ADF - Pass array to a SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure data factory pipeline which calls a SQL stored procedure to perform some operation. I have an array within my pipeline and I want to pass this array to the stored procedure. I tried to create a custom type in SQL server and tried passing the array as input. But it didn't work as the activity does not have a data type for parameter as array. Any idea how to pass an array to a SQL stored procedure?

Screenshot of ADF option

[image]

Comment: Please use String as the data type. How did you get the array? Is the the output of some active?

Comment: @LeonYue - I get all the file names from a fileshare location using "Get MetaData" task. I need to pass it to the Stored procedure. If string is the only way, is there any easy way to convert the array to string?

Comment: you don't need to convert it. The output of the Get MetaData is already  string data type. I have the question , are the parameters of the stored procedure  the element of the array?

Comment: I am trying to get all the files from a folder. So the output of get metadata has a field named childItems and it is an array

Comment: Use a string and then convert your array into a JSON object, and then use OPENJSON to parse the JSON array into a table

Comment: Hi @user12526031, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The output 'childitems' of the get metadata is a json object, not an array.
[image]

The pipeline should like this firstly: pass the childitems(file names) to the stored procedure:
[image]

I don't know how you program your stored procedure, but just make some changes to accept the json parameter.

Ref: [How to Insert JSON Data into SQL Server Database](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-to-Insert-JSON-Data-into-SQL-Server-Database/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string()` function to convert a JSON object to a string while passing a parameter; e.g.,

```
@string(activity('Get Metadata2').output.childItems)
```